# How to calculate the partial derivatives of the composition $F(u(s,t),v(s,t))$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

[image]

Could someone help me to understand how to do this problem?

I believe Partial Derivatives are used. Thanks!

Comment: This is just an application of the multivariable chain rule. You should try googling that term, or look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions).

Comment: Try to write more descriptive titles in the future. Also, see  [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and advice on [asking good questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**.  By the chain rule,
$$W_s=F_uu_s+F_vv_s\ .$$
Make sure you substitute in the correct values of $s$ and $t$.

Comment: can you explain the terms in the equation above?

Comment: $W_s$ is the same as $\partial W/\partial s$, and so on.  If you have not studied these yet you need to do the basics of partial differentiation, for example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZwdHLbmFJs), before trying chain rule problems.